# how to print $ in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to td value with an updated $ price. I am doing like this

```
$('#memberSubscription').find('tr#1').find('td:eq(2)').html('$' + certificatePrice + ' USD');
```

but console showing like below

```
  $('#memberSubscription').find('tr#1').find('td:eq(2)').html('</div> + certificatePrice + ' USD');
```

How to handle this?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: `'$'` will be interpreted as a literal character.  Not sure what issue you are seeing.  It's not going to automatically convert a character $ to </div>.  https://jsfiddle.net/not41fcu/

Comment: You can use the html entity &#36; to get the dollar sign ($)

Comment: @Taplar indeed. I'm very confused how the second output comes up. Not only is the *string* `'$'` replaced with `'</div>` but also the closing apostrophe is suddenly gone. Not sure how the console is related to this, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the &#36; html entity to get the dollar sign:

```
$('#memberSubscription').find('tr#1').find('td:eq(2)').html('&#36;' + certificatePrice + ' USD');
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what the issue is.

Comment: `$` does not need to be escaped as an HTML to be put into the DOM. If there is a problem with OP's code, it's likely to still be present even with this substitution.

Comment: Correct, it does not explain what the issue is. It is not clear from the question if the goal is to solve a problem or find out the cause of it.

Comment: Hard to solve a problem if you don't know the cause, eh?  The goal is to always identify the problem, explain it, and solve it.  If the OP has not explained the problem, it is not yet ready for an answer

Comment: @James123 If this solves your issue, then something else is going on.  As stated in the above comments, jQuery is not going to automatically convert a dollar sign to a closing div.  If you are seeing that happen, **something** other than jQuery is doing it.  This change may circumvent that, but you are avoiding the problem, not coming to understand it.

Comment: I agree with @Taplar, there is probably a separate problem that's causing this. Maybe malformed HTML?

Answer (score -2):

This is a silly mistake and easy to  fix very easy to fix so first you should apply an id to just the item to make it easyer

```js
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "</div> &#36; certificate Price USD";
//or to console log becuse this is confusing how to worded this
console.log('$ certificate Price USD');
//or jquery way
$('#text').html(' </div> &#36; certificate Price USD ');
//but realy whats the difference with venila and jquery just do a venilajs function like so
function sethtml(text, id){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = (text);
}
//then
sethtml('&#36; certificate Price USD', 'text');
//i see no reason for jquery though inless your allready using it
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='text'></span>
```

Comment: Realy this is my first post and you didnt explain well either